# How could I create an intent in a button to open a specific folder?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent

How could I create an intent in a (button) to open a specific folder? I've tried several methods but all showed only recent files, I would like to open the folder that my application created to store the generated .pdf files, but in case I didn't want to select any file, just show the user the folder the .pdf files, it would save me from creating a tutorial to show the folder path to the user, thanks everyone!

```
encontrar = findViewById(R.id.encontrarArquivos);
    encontrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Easy_Arquivos/");
            Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider" ,file);
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you organize your files? Where do you store them and how? Please add some relevant code.

Comment: First thanks for answering me, I tried other ways and got it with the "FileProvider" method, but now when I click on (Button) it opens my Folder as if it were a PDF File, I would like to just open the Folder and shows the pdf files.

Comment: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` The second call to setFlags() will erase the flags set with the first call. You can call setFlags() only once and have to OR the flags.

Comment: Thanks for answering me! In my code, I was just intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
so in LogCat I was going to need to add intent.setFlags (intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
only this way the application worked, but I was not successful in what I wanted

Comment: A FileProvider is for files. Not for folders.

Comment: the second flag is called on intent and not Intent. If you want both of them add them like this: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: As for your question, I think you need to look at the Storage Access Network and document providers in particular: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: ok thank you very much for your attention! I will try, but how then could I just open folders?

Comment: intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Uri.parse(defaultPath) ); Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: I'll take a look and read about, thanks Nikos Hidalgo and blackapps